# How to find JSON data as ember.js wants?

Tags: python, django, json, ember.js, django-rest-framework

I am new in django and ember.js. Can you help me about how to find correct JSOn for ember.js

My Code is Here -

In models.py -

```
from django.db import models

class Confusion(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

In serializers.py -

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from confusion.models import Confusion

class ConfusionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Confusion
    fields = ('id', 'title', 'description')
```

In views.py -

```
from rest_framework import generics

from confusion.models import Confusion

from confusion.serializers import ConfusionSerializer

class ConfusionList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = Confusion.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ConfusionSerializer

class ConfusionDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):

    queryset = Confusion.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ConfusionSerializer
```

Now I am getting Output Like -

```
[{"id": 1, "title": "Career", "description": "I am confused about my career"}]
```

But I need:

```
{"confusion":{"id": 1, "title": "Career", "description": "I am confused about my career"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out Toran Billups' [ember-data-django-rest-adapter](https://github.com/toranb/ember-data-django-rest-adapter). It should do exactly what you need.

Take a look at the [README](https://github.com/toranb/ember-data-django-rest-adapter/blob/master/README.md) — for basic use, all the extra set-up is on the JavaScript side.

(I basically quote...)

1. Include the `ember-data-django-rest-adapter.js` after `ember-data.js` in your HTML/build system
2. Add the custom adapter:

   ```
    App.Store = DS.DjangoRESTStore.extend({
       adapter: DS.DjangoRESTAdapter.create()
    });
   ```

That's it. (In particular is there something you can't get working?)